# Decision behind libsodium AEAD implementation

Tags: cryptography, libsodium

[RFC 7539](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) defines its AEAD construction as follows:

```
chacha20_aead_encrypt(aad, key, iv, constant, plaintext):
   nonce = constant | iv
   otk = poly1305_key_gen(key, nonce)
   ciphertext = chacha20_encrypt(key, 1, nonce, plaintext)
   mac_data = aad | pad16(aad)
   mac_data |= ciphertext | pad16(ciphertext)
   mac_data |= num_to_4_le_bytes(aad.length)
   mac_data |= num_to_4_le_bytes(ciphertext.length)
   tag = poly1305_mac(mac_data, otk)
   return (ciphertext, tag)
```

On the other hand, [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) implements it as follows:

```
chacha20_aead_encrypt(aad, key, iv, constant, plaintext):
   nonce = constant | iv
   otk = poly1305_key_gen(key, nonce)
   ciphertext = chacha20_encrypt(key, 1, nonce, plaintext)
   mac_data = aad
   mac_data |= num_to_8_le_bytes(aad.length)
   mac_data |= ciphertext
   mac_data |= num_to_8_le_bytes(ciphertext.length)
   tag = poly1305_mac(mac_data, otk)
   return (ciphertext, tag)
```

Basically libsodium does not uses padding and interleaves data and metadata (its length) on its Poly1305 pass. This is very unfriendly for optimization due to block alignment issues: after computing the MAC of additional data, next data does not need to be block aligned, so you can not use a highly optimized and interleaved Chacha20-Poly1305 construct.

What is the reason behind this decision?

Comment: Why not ask the author? A well phrased quesetion is generally answered. The nice thing about crypto is that we have the luxury that most of the cryptographers are still alive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305 "*libsodium implements three versions of the ChaCha20-Poly1305 construction*". The first two are as follows:

- The original construction can safely encrypt up to 2^64 messages with the same
  key (even more with most protocols), without any practical limit to the size
  of a message (up to 2^64 bytes for a 128-bit tag).
- The IETF variant. It can safely encrypt a pratically unlimited number of
  messages, but individual messages cannot exceed 64*(2^32)-64 bytes
  (approximatively 256 GB).

The one you describe is the "original construction". The nonces supported by the original construction are smaller than the IETF version (64-bits vs 96-bits) and the AEAD construction is different, as well, as you observed.

My guess: the "original construction" was developed before the IETF RFC was written. libsodium is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software) which was initially released in 2008. The IETF RFC was written in 2015.